# Is this "trick" allowed with an arbitrary inner products?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Say I have two sequences, $\{x_n\} \rightarrow x$ and $\{y_n\} \rightarrow y$, in a Hilbert space. Is this the following allowed?: $$\langle x_n,y\rangle - \langle x_n,y_n\rangle = \overline{\langle y,x_n\rangle} - \overline{\langle y_n, x_n \rangle} = \overline{\langle y-y_n,x_n\rangle} = \langle x_n,y-y_n\rangle$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is always valid. The fact that you have convergent sequences doesn't even matter. The inner product is always linear in the first argument and semilinear in its second argument.

Usually it is part of the definition of the inner product that the inner product is linear in the first argument, i.e. $\langle x+x',y\rangle = \langle x,y \rangle +\langle x', y\rangle$ and $\langle \lambda x ,y \rangle = \lambda \langle x,y\rangle$, and that it is conjugate symmetric, i.e. $\langle x,y \rangle = \overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$.

You can then show, using your "trick", that the inner product is semilinear in the second argument, i.e. $\langle x,y+y'\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle +\langle x,y'\rangle$ and $\langle x,\lambda y\rangle = \overline{\lambda}\langle x, y\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks. It seemed like it had to be true based on the definition, but I was uncertain.

Comment: I was sure I did, sorry.